# WMIC command runs fine with a local account, hangs with an AD account using remote logon

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

For some reason, this command runs fine locally:

wmic group where sid="S-1-5-32-545" get name

But hangs for 8hours+ when ran under an AD account via remote desktop.

Is it possible there's a GPO policy preventing this? What exactly does that wmic command do? (it's being summoned by a script left by a previous admin).

Comment: What application? Does it maintain an installation log?

Comment: Are you sure that the freezing is related to that part of your script? That SID should always be the "Users" group. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/243330

Comment: I'm pretty sure. I've tested running only "wmic group" in this machine, and it freezes. This machine is part of a huge corporate AD. Could this explain why it takes so long to resume?